# What's the difference between using autoprefixer within gulp-postcss or outside of it?

Tags: gulp, autoprefixer, postcss, gulp-plugin, gulp-autoprefixer

I'm using `Gulp` and have used the [Gulp Autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-autoprefixer) standalone such as:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src('scss/**/*.scss')
        //.................
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: [
              //..........
            ],
        }))
        //............
});
```

...but then I see the [Gulp Postcss plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-postcss) which seems to wrap the usage of a [non-gulp autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer) such as:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src('scss/**/*.scss')
    //.................
            .pipe(sass())
            .pipe(postcss([
                autoprefixer({
                    browsers: [
                        //.......
                    ],
                }),
            ]))
    //............
});
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Autoprefixer is just a PostCSS plugin. There is no way to run it without PostCSS.

`gulp-autoprefixer` hides PostCSS inside. Like a shortcut for `gulp-postcss(autoprefixer)`. It is unofficial way to run Autoprefixer.

Autoprefixer author recommends to use only `gulp-postcss`, because:

- You will get Autoprefixer updates faster.
- You can combine Autoprefixer with other PostCSS-based tools to improve performance. Parsing step (the longest in CSS processing) will executed only once for all PostCSS-based tools (including Autoprefixer).
- It is official way and Autoprefixer and PostCSS team test it better.

Comment: Thanks for the rundown Andrey!